# Does value of ICalRecurrenceId ever change for each instance of recurring meeting

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I want to import all the meetings for a number of users into a database. I'm using the EWS Managed API and C#

When I import meetings from each mailbox, I might encounter the same meeting multiple times if each of the users have been invited to that meeting.

For single instance meetings I can use the value of `ICalUid` to get the unique ID of the meeting and so I will be able to only store one instance of it.

However, for recurring meetings it is not clear what additional field I should use (along with `ICalUid`) to identity each instance of a recurring meeting series.

Can I reliably use `ICalRecurrenceId`? Will this value ever change? Will it be consistent when the meeting instance is imported from multiple mailboxes?
Is there a better field that I can/should use to meet my needs?

Note - I've looked at using the `ItemId` field but this returns a different value when the same meeting is returned from different mailboxes. I need to be able to identity a meeting instance regardless of what mailbox it was imported from.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been here for years but I hope this answer gives some information for people who need.

- `ICalUid`: is the UID of the meeting and will not be changed across calendars.
- `ICalRecurrenceId`: is the original start time of each occurrence of the recurrence meeting.
- All the occurrences of a recurrence meeting will have same `ICalUid` but `ICalRecurrenceId` will be different.
- On start time modification of an occurrence, `ICalUid` and `ICalRecurrenceId` will not be changed.
- On start time modification of a recurrence meeting, `ICalUid` will be retained but the `ICalRecurrenceId` will be changed for all occurrences

So to resolve your problem, the combination of the two values will be good enough.

Comment: Is that true that `ICalRecurrenceId` always eq to `originalStart`? So in the case of "on start time modification of a recurrence meeting", every occurrence will change its `originalStart` as well?

Comment: `ICalRecurrenceId` will not be changed if it is Occurrence(Exception) change. If you update the series, actually the whole existing occurrences will be replaced so for the `ICalRecurrenceId` of each. I'm not sure about the  `originalStart`. In the RFC spec the `ICalRecurrenceId` is not necessarily stored as time value, can be other kinds of data but microsoft uses the time value.

Comment: So for time-wise, you'd better go with `originalStart`. Combination of `ICalUid ` and `ICalRecurrenceId` is to identify an occurrence of a series meeting.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried using ICalRecurrenceId, but it's possible that ICalUID + Start (DateTime) should allow to properly identify.

Comment: But if a specific instance of a recurring meeting series is updated and moved to a different time will ICalUID + Start (DateTime) point to the new updated time or the original instance time? I need to be able to correctly identity each instance so I know to update the instance in my DB and not insert a new record

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem.

Comment: From my experiments, the `ICalRecurrenceId` does not change, even if the start datetime of an occurrence is changed. It's the original start time for the occurence. Thus, the `ICalUid` combined with the `ICalRecurrenceId` can be used to identify a single occurrence across different mailboxes. (Han's answer seems correct.)